# Turning an Array Formula from Excel into an Array Formula in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets

I am trying to tinker with a formula in a sample Excel spreadsheet found online in order to make it work in Google Sheets using an array formula.

The formula has to do with setting up an array to find multiple results using multiple search criteria.

Here is the sample spreadsheet: http://www.get-digital-help.com/wp-content/uploads/2009/05/multiple-criteria-lookup-with-multiple-results1.xls

I recreated the spreadsheet in GSheets and am working with trying to wrap it with an array formula but it only returns one result:

=ARRAYFORMULA(INDEX($C$3:$C$17,SMALL(IF(ISNUMBER((SEARCH($F$3,$C$3:$C$17))*(SEARCH($H$3,$B$3:$B$17))),ROW($B$3:$B$17)-MIN(ROW($B$3:$B$17))+1,""),ROW(A1))))

Answer (score 0):

You need to Drag fill the formula down ( just like in Excel).

`INDEX` won't return a array of results ( unless it's the same row/column)

Comment: Is there any way to use a single array formula to do this?  I am trying to use multiple criteria and generate multiple results.  I would use a query but I have 1000 lines and that would slow my spreadsheet down dramatically

Comment: The formula that you linked specifically requires you to drag fill down. See the last `ROW(A1)` in your formula. Row A1=1. When you drag fill to the next row, it changes to Row (A2) =2. The `IF` creates a array of results ( but with numerous blanks and falses). If you simply remove `INDEX` and `SMALL` You will have a array of results, but messed up bad. To remove blanks and falses, This array is fed into `SMALL`. `ROW (A1)` gives the first smallest value in the array, `ROW (A2)` gives the second smallest value and so on.

Comment: Check my other answer

Answer (score 0):

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(JOIN("•¶",IF(ISNUMBER((SEARCH($F$3,$C$3:$C$17))*(SEARCH($H$3,$B$3:$B$17))),$C$3:$C$17&$B$3:$B$17,"")),"•¶")))
```

Just providing this as a alternative. This will give a array of results as requested by OP. But there are limits to this formula. The total character limit in `JOIN` should not exceed 50,000.

***Note: Only for Google Sheets***

Comment: Mark this as solution by clicking ✔ on the left of this post.